# sed -i touching files that it doesn't change

Tags: sed, ksh

Someone on our server ran `sed -i 's/$var >> $var2/$var > $var2/ *`  to change inserts to overwrites in some bash scripts in a common directory. No big deal, it was tested first with `grep` and it returned the expected results that only his files would be touched.

He ran the script and now 1200 files of the 1400 in the folder have a new modified date, yet as far as we can tell, only his small handful of files were actually changed.

1. Why would sed 'touch' a file that it's not changing.
2. Why would it only 'touch' a portion of the files and not all of them.
3. Did it actually change something (maybe some trailing white space or something totally unexpected because of the `$`'s in the sed regex)?

Comment: Is it gnu sed? Others might vary.

Comment: As a comment on pt 3 (this is not an answer): if you use version control (git/subversion/etc) on your scripts, then questions like this of what changed or didn't change can always be clearly answered.

Comment: I love version control, but I have no control over this server. Everything on it is out of date and it would take an act of congress to get git installed. But yes, I completely 100% agree with you. Until then... nightly backups and prayers.

Comment: @Flexo  GNU sed version 4.1.4

Comment: Is there anything to prevent you from extracting the file tree from backups (or just `rsync` periodically if policy permits) and run Git in the mirrored tree?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When GNU `sed` successfully edits a file "in-place," its timestamp is updated. To understand why, let's review how edit "in-place" is done:

1. A temporary file is created to hold the output.
2. `sed` processes the input file, sending output to the temporary file.
3. If a backup file extension was specified, the input file is renamed to the backup file.
4. Whether a backup is created or not, the temporary output is moved ([`rename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html)) to the input file.

GNU `sed` does not track whether any changes were made to the file.  Whatever is in the temporary output file is moved to the input file via `rename`.

There is a nice benefit to this procedure: [POSIX requires that `rename` be atomic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html).  Consequently, the input file is never in a mangled state: it is either the original file or the modified file and never part way in-between.

As a result of this procedure, any file that `sed` successfully processes will have its timestamp changed.

#### Example

Let's consider this `inputfile`:

```
$ cat inputfile
this is
a test.
```

Now, under the supervision of `strace`, let's run `sed -i` on it in a way guaranteed to cause no changes:

```
$ strace sed -i 's/XXX/YYY/' inputfile
```

The edited result looks like:

```
execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "-i", "s/XXX/YYY/", "inputfile"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
[...snip...]
open("inputfile", O_RDONLY)             = 4
[...snip...]
open("./sediWWqLI", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 6
[...snip...]
read(4, "this is\na test.\n", 4096)     = 16
write(6, "this is\n", 8)                = 8
write(6, "a test.\n", 8)                = 8
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
[...snip...]
close(4)                                = 0
[...snip...]
close(6)                                = 0
[...snip...]
rename("./sediWWqLI", "inputfile")      = 0
```

As you can see, `sed` opens the input file, `inputfile`, on file handle 4.  It then creates a temporary file, `./sediWWqLI` on file handle 6, to hold the output.  It reads from the input file and writes it unchanged to the output file.  When this is done, a call to `rename` is made to overwrite `inputfile`, changing its timestamp.

#### GNU `sed` source code

The relevant source code is in the `execute.c` file of the `sed` directory of [the source](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sed/sed_4.2.1-10.debian.tar.gz). From version 4.2.1:

```
  ck_fclose (input->fp);
  ck_fclose (output_file.fp);
  if (strcmp(in_place_extension, "*") != 0)
    {
      char *backup_file_name = get_backup_file_name(target_name);
      ck_rename (target_name, backup_file_name, input->out_file_name);
      free (backup_file_name);
    }

  ck_rename (input->out_file_name, target_name, input->out_file_name);
  free (input->out_file_name);
```

`ck_rename` is a cover function for the stdio function `rename`.  The source for `ck_rename` is in `sed/utils.c`.

As you can see, no flag is kept to determine whether the file actually changed or not.  `rename` is called regardless.

#### Files whose timestamps were not updated

As for the 200 of the 1400 files whose timestamps did not change, that would mean that `sed` somehow failed on those files.  One possibility would be a permissions issue.

### `sed -i` and Symbolic Links

As noted by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), applying `sed -i` to a symbolic link leads to a surprising result.  `sed -i` **does not update the file pointed to by the symbolic link**.  Instead, `sed -i` **overwrites the symbolic link** with a new regular file.

This is a result of the call that `sed` makes to the STDIO `rename`.  As documented by `man 2 rename`:

> if newpath refers to a symbolic link the link will be overwritten.

mklement0 reports that this is also true of the (BSD) `sed` on Mac OSX 10.10.

Comment: I had assumed this was the case for edit in place. Thanks for dropping the source code in the answer! The failure on the 200 is still a bit of a mystery since the permissions seem to be in line with the other files, but perhaps it was something else that caused them to fail. Either way, I think you are right on. Thanks!

Comment: Great analysis; without checking the source code, I've found that GNU `sed` (as of at least 4.2.2) correctly preserves the _permissions_ of the original input file. However, sadly, if the original file was a _symlink_, it is replaced with a _regular_ file.  What is also  _not_ preserved is the _creation_ timestamp of the original file. BSD `sed` (as of at least the version that comes with OSX 10.10) seems to behave the same in all respects.

Comment: @mklement0 Wow! That is an important observation.  While I can understand the author's doing it that way, it certainly is not what I would expect for _"in-place"_ editing.  (I have updated the answer with that information.)

Comment: @John1024: Thanks, and fully agreed. The woefully disregarded `ed` is your friend when it comes to _true_ in-place editing, which preserves the existing `inode` - it comes with the caveat that it invariably reads the original file into memory _as a whole_.

Comment: "Whether a backup is created or not, the temporary output is moved (rename) to the input file."

Couldn't a diff be applied in-between to prevent this if the file did not change ?

Answer (score 12):

I use the following workaround, i.e. look at each file separatedely, use grep to check if the file contains the string and then use sed. Not very nice, but works...

```bash
for i in *;do grep mytext "$i" && sed -i -e 's/mytext/replacement/g' "$i";done
```