# How to use sed to replace a string within a string?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I read the following article "[Using grep and sed to find and replace a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178498/using-grep-and-sed-to-find-and-replace-a-string)" but how can I extend it to chain multiple greps. For example I have the following directory/file structure

```
dir1/metadata.txt
dir2/metadata.txt
```

dir1/metadata.txt has

```
filename1 '= 1.0.0'
filename2 '= 1.0.0'
```

dir2/metadata.txt has

```
filename1     '= 1.0.0'
long_filename '= 1.0.0'
```

In other words, both dir1/metadata.txt and dir2/metadata.txt contain "filename '1.0.0'" but the spaces between the "filename" and the "'1.0.0'" in each file is different.

Now I want to replace filename1's associated version to '2.0.0' in ALL metadata.txt files so the resulting files look like...

dir1/metadata.txt has

```
filename1 '= 2.0.0'
filename2 '= 1.0.0'
```

dir2/metadata.txt has

```
filename1     '= 2.0.0'
long_filename '= 1.0.0'
```

I'm trying

```
find . -name metadata.txt | xargs grep filename1 | sed -i "s/1\.0\.0/2.0.0/g" <some option here>
```

but I know the "some option here" part. Any clues?

Comment: do you need to change all `*filename*` ( e.g. `filename2` and `long_filename` ) too or only `filename1` ?

Comment: tivn: Only filename1. filename2 and long_filename remain unchanged

Comment: shelter: your command will only change ONE file

Comment: sed simply CANNOT operate on strings but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460 for a workaround.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good tip in general, but the issue here is not how to _generically_ replace strings with `sed`, but how to combine `find` with `sed` (with _specific_ search and replacement strings, for which the OP has already provided the required escaping).

Comment: I understand but I thought it was worth mentioning given the subject line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

Linux:

```
find . -name metadata.txt \
  -exec sed -i "s/^\(filename1[[:space:]]\{1,\}'= \)1\.0\.0/\12.0.0/" {} +
```

OSX / BSD:

```
find . -name metadata.txt \
  -exec sed -i '' "s/^\(filename1[[:space:]]\{1,\}'= \)1\.0\.0/\12.0.0/" {} +
```

<sup>Note: The only reason why platform-specific commands are required is that GNU `sed` and `BSD` sed interpret the *nonstandard* `-i` option, which specifies the *suffix* to use for an optional *backup* of the original file, differently: GNU `sed` considers the option-argument for `-i` *optional*, whereas *BSD* `sed` considers it *mandatory*, requiring an *explicit* argument to specify the empty string (indicating the desire *not* to create a backup file)</sup>

- `exec ... +` is a `find` feature that invokes the specified command with as many matching paths as can fit on a single command line, *potentially* resulting in *multiple* invocations, but *typically* resulting in only *1*, which makes the invocation *efficient*.
- `"s/\(filename1[[:space:]]\{1,\}'= \)1\.0\.0/\12.0.0/"` is a POSIX-compliant `sed` script that matches literal `filename1` at the beginning of a line, followed by a variable amount of whitespace (`[[:space:]]\{1,\}`), followed by literal `'= 1.0.0`, and replaces the `1.0.0.` with `2.0.0`.
- Note that if there are `metadata.txt` files that do *not* have lines beginning with `filename1`, they are *still* rewritten, because `sed`'s `-i` option blindly "updates" the input files given (read: creates a new file that then replaces the original). If that is undesired, consider [John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29998292/45375).

POSIX-compliance notes:

- The `-exec ... +` variant of `find`'s `-exec` primary has been part of POSIX since 2001 (POSIX.1-2001 / IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 / SUS v3 - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/; thanks, @JonathanLeffler)
- By contrast, `sed`'s `-i` option for *in-place updating* is *not* POSIX-compliant - so you may have to work around that.

Comment: Use `+` in place of `\;`?

Comment: According to [Apple's `man find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), its current version of `find` supports `{} +`.   Of course, there will be other or older BSD systems that don't support it.

Comment: Thanks, @John1024: `find`'s  `-exec .... +` _is_ POSIX-compliant (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but `sed`'s `-i` is not.

Comment: The `+` is from POSIX 2004 ([`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)), so those systems that don't support it are at least a decade out of date.  That isn't to say they don't exist, nor that it isn't worth mentioning the fallback.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, very good.  Plus 1 for both GNU and BSD versions.

Comment: For RH Linux, how do I change it so I don't care if there is a comma (",") between filename1 and '1.0.0', and it can be anywhere; IOW "filename1,    '1.0.0'" or "filename1    ,'1.0.0'"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for the POSIX hint; from what I understand, POSIX 2004 is the same as POSIX.1-2001 (IEEE Std 1003.1-2001) - SUS v3, only with _technical corrections_; thus, we're talking 14 years ago - is that your understanding too?

Comment: Yup: the 'title page' for the [POSIX 2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) documentation says: ***Abstract:*** _The 2004 edition incorporates Technical Corrigendum Number 1 and Technical Corrigendum 2 addressing problems discovered since the approval of the 2001 edition. These are mainly due to resolving integration issues raised by the merger of the Base documents._  So there is room to argue that manufacturers who have not gotten around to adding `+` to `find` have had all of thirteen years (2002-2014) and bits of 2001 and 2015 in which to fix the issue.

Comment: @ChrisF: The simplest approach is to replace `[[:space:]]\{1,\}` with `[[:space:],]\{1,\}`, but this is slightly more permissive than what you asked for; if you know that there is _at most_ one comma, this should work, however.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name metadata.txt -exec grep -l --null filename1 {} + | xargs -0 sed -i "/^filename1 /{s/'= 1\.0\.0'/'= 2.0.0'/;}"
```

`sed -i` will update the timestamp of every file it processes regardless of whether it changes the contents of the file.  This is because, in operation, `sed -i` [creates a new file for each file processed and then overwrites the old file with the new file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075334/3030305).  To limit this, the above code uses `grep` to select only the files that might need modification and sends only those file names, via a pipeline, to `sed -i` for the update.

If the timestamp/overwriting issue is not important, consider [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075334/3030305) which eliminates the need for a pipeline, simplifying the command.

#### How it works

- `find . -name metadata.txt -exec grep -l --null filename1 {} +`

  This produces the list of files name `metadata.txt` that also contain `filename`.

  The `--null` tells `grep` to separate file names with the NUL character.
- `xargs -0 sed -i "/^filename1 /{s/'= 1\.0\.0'/'= 2.0.0'/;}"`

  This applies `sed -i` to change in-place the files whose names were returned by the above `find` command.

  In more detail:

  - `/^filename1 /`

    This selects lines that start with `filename1` followed by a space.  This assures that we match neither `sfilename1` nor `filename12`.
  - `s/'= 1\.0\.0'/'= 2.0.0'/`

    This changes the version number for the selected lines.  (This assumes only one space after the equal sign.  If this assumption is not correct, we can easily change it.)

  The `-0` option to `xargs` tells it to expect its input to be a NUL-separated list of file names.  This makes the pipeline safe even if the file names include spaces, newlines, or other difficult characters.

Comment: Be aware that while the `-exec` handles spaces in file names, the `xargs` won't.  You can fix that with the GNU toolchain by using `grep -lZ` and `xargs -0` so that the file names are terminated with a null byte (instead of a newline). Alternatively, you can execute the `sed` in the `-exec` option. The downside of using `-exec` is that it might edit a file which does not contain `filename1`. That's relatively unlikely to matter, even if there are thousands of files to process, unless there are reasons not to risk modifying the 'last changed time' of the files unless something actually changes.

Comment: The 'might modify files that don't need modifying' observation applies to the other answer.  I like the simpler 'match the marker; substitute the relevant text on the marked line' operation in the `sed` script.  I don't understand why people insist on using a single line for shell scripts — 'one-liner' is a pejorative term in APL.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks.  I updated the answer to include `-Z`/`-0`.  I kept the grep-to-sed pipeline because the `last changed time` issue does surprise/confuse users who aren't expecting it.  Separately,  I found well-written APL scripts to be quite readable. I wouldn't mind if shell tools were rewritten by someone with Ken Iverson's eye for logical consistency.

Comment: John, @JonathanLeffler: Good point re timestamps (++); I've updated my answer to mention the issue and linked to this one as an alternative. John, perhaps you can update your answer to explain when your answer is preferable over mine.

Comment: John: If you change `-Z` to `--null`, the command will work on BSD systems (including OSX) too. @JonathanLeffler: The POSIX-compliant solution to handling embedded spaces (assuming there are no filenames with _newlines_) is to use `xargs -I {} sed ... {}`, but note that that inevitably invokes `sed` once for every file.

Comment: Note that BSD `grep` has a `-Z` option, but it is wholly different from the GNU `grep -Z`: it makes it work like `zgrep` (so it searches compressed files too).

Comment: @mklement0 I updated the answer to `--null`, mentioned the issue with timestamps, and linked back to your answer.