# sed changes files date

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using sed in this way.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/$3/$4/g" {} +
```

but it changes the dates of all files even if it does not find the string in a file.
Can I avoid it?

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075334/3064489) it seems not possible to avoid this behavior of `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You can first grep your file, to see if there is something to replace:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q "$3" '{}' ';' -exec sed -i "s/$3/$4/g" '{}' ';'
```

Otherwise it is not possible to avoid the timestamp update, as `sed` basically re-creates the file, when `-i` is used:

> --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.
>
> When the end of the file is reached, the **temporary file is renamed to the output** file’s original name.

[GNU sed Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

Comment: It's functions correctly. Now only updated file have the date modified.